# Alternative form of this equation without the product symbol?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, functions, products

For a programming case, I need to redefine this equation, but for any value of 'n' and without the 'product' symbol

$$\prod_{i=1}^n  \Bigg(1-exp\bigg(-0.5\Big(\frac{c}{s_{i}}\Big)^2\bigg)\Bigg)^{m_{i}}$$

Or at least prove that it is not possible

Thanks!

EDIT: I need all of the Si to be together in the same term, either as a sum or as a product. I do not know if it is possible though.

Comment: Are you sure there's meant to be an equals sign there? That is not an equation that makes sense.

Comment: There seems to be a problem here. Did you mean to ask the question without the equal sign? $\prod_{i=1}  ^n$ doesn't mean anything without something you're taking the product of.

Comment: That's right. There shouldn't be an equal sign. I fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is no equal sign, call the quantity you want $$X=\prod_{i=1}^n  \Bigg(1-exp\bigg(-0.5\Big(\frac{c}{s_{i}}\Big)^2\bigg)\Bigg)^{m_{i}}$$.

Then $\log X = \sum_{i=1}^n m_i \log(1-exp\bigg(-0.5\Big(\frac{c}{s_{i}}\Big)^2\bigg)\Bigg)$. Thus $X = exp\Bigg[ \sum_{i=1}^n m_i \log(1-exp\bigg(-0.5\Big(\frac{c}{s_{i}}\Big)^2\bigg)\Bigg)\Bigg]$. Perhaps this idea may help? I'm not sure if a sum is better than a product, or what exactly your goal is here.

Comment: I actually need all of the Si to be together in a same term, either as a product or as a sum. But don't know if it is possible for this equation. I was not so clear in my question. Having it in this way, though, will be easier to compute for my particular case. Thanks! (each index is an element of a 4D and a 2D matrix)